# xml data not being returned using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, get, alexa-internet

I am trying to get the page popularity of a site

```
<POPULARITY URL="google.com/" SOURCE="panel" TEXT="1"/>
```

using alexa api.  If I post

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=http://www.google.com
```

into the browser i get a xml response but using ajax I get nothing returned

```
$.ajax({    type: "GET",
            url: "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=http://www.google.com",
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success:function(data){

            alert(data); 

            }

        });
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would structure it like this:

```
$.get(ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
  });
```

Also, I think you want be doing a `get` for the data (rather than `$.post` and then specifying `get` later on).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's because you're trying to load an xml file which is not from your domain.  Most browsers will block this by default because it breaks cross-domain javascript rules.

If you look in the console in your developer tools (F12 in most browsers) you'll see an error similar to this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=http://www.google.com&_=1337464540283.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The easiest way around this (presuming you are running PHP) is to create a small php file which wraps the xml file on your own server and load it from there.

see this question for an example:

[Ajax: Load XML from different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895045/ajax-load-xml-from-different-domain)